# Elegant and cheap way to transform lists in python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list of numbers I'd like to increment and I'm only interested in the incremented values, not the original ones afterwards. What is the most pythonic way to do it *in situ*, **without copying** the list?

Does

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = [i+1 for i in a]
```

result in an intermediate copy of `a`, or does the python interpreter optimize this?

Unfortunately, my python knowledge is still superficial. My mother tongue is C++.

Comment: Run `[i for i in range(5)]` and then see what the value of `_` is.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what `_` is. Could you explain your hint?

Comment: The Python compiler may do all kinds of optimization. What exactly are you concerned about here? Just speed? If so, then don't worry about it.

Comment: Yes, just speed. I'm still curious what `_` is, though.

Comment: Note that if you're used to C++, your intuitions about what factors will be important to efficiency are likely to be wrong for Python. For example, despite creating a new list instead of reusing the original, the list comprehension is actually faster than a mutative solution.

Comment: That's an underscore, Python uses it to store values it you don't give it a place to put (an unassigned list comprehension for example). If speed is what you want then list comprehension are fine. They are pretty fast as far as Python is concerned. It's an O(n) operation. If you want to avoid slowdowns form memeory being used up you could always use a generator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without copying the list you can do this:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: id(a)
Out[2]: 48701592

In [3]: for i in xrange(len(a)): # range(len(a)) for python 3
   ...:     a[i] += 1
   ...:     

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [2, 3, 4]

In [5]: id(a)
Out[5]: 48701592
```

Comment: Note that Python 3 does not support `xrange()` anymore. Use `range()` instead, it has similar semantics.

Comment: Seems like using `for i in range(len(a)): a[i] += 1` provides no improvement over `a = [i+1 for i in a]`, since `range(len(a))` creates a list of integers just as long as `a`.

Comment: `range()` is `xrange()` in Python3 if I'm not mistaken,

Comment: @IanAuld: You are mistaken. It's the other way 'round. `range()` in Python 2 is actually an unpleasant legacy.

Comment: @Olaf After checking yes Python 3's `range` is `xrange` from Python 2. `range` was removed and `xrange` was renamed.

Answer (score 3):

There is one problem with the intergers in the list: These are actually immutable objects, so if you increment an integer, it will actually be repaced by a new object anyway.

So, although a list comprehension *will* create an intermediate copy, the overhead might not be that much of a problem. If in doubt, you can profile the alternatives using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html).

A often overlooked problem will arise if there are other references to the list:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> for i in xrange(len(a)):   # range() in Python 3!!
...     a[i] += 1
... 
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you create a new list for a, b will not see these modifications of course:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> a = [i + 1 for i in a]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, the answer is actually: it depends. Use the for loop

Comment: A good point to remember and one that often catches the unwary moving from other languages ( it has caught me)

Comment: @paisanco: Yes, that is a very common pitfall with Python. People tend to assign an object to conserve its previous state, modify the original and wonder why the "copy" has also changed. Just be aware the names you use to access the objects are actually pointers not the objects themselves. Copying them just copies the value of the pointer (basically, it is all a bit more complicated, but still quite straigth forward).

Answer (score 2):

Another option using numpy array

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([1,2,3])
A=A+1
```

Comment: Would this be cheaper then @Akavall's answer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `numpy` will add a lot of overhead you don't need if this is all you are using it for.

Comment: For a 3-element array, sure.For a much larger one, that's another matter. I can't divine the intent of the OPs question. Taken at face value  it probably is overkill relative to @Akavali

Comment: Just curious: Is a numpy array in all aspects of its interface compatible to a list?

Comment: No. If that's a requirement for the OP  I'll withdraw the answer.

Comment: I meant the question to be more general then just for list interface, so please don't remove the answer. Also, I used integers just as an example. Suppose that instead I need a container for large objects, on each one of which I need to perform an expensive operation. What would be the best solution then?

Comment: If you are interested in numerical computation (inferred from your profile) Numpy is worth learning about. Lists are more flexible as far as the data types they can contains and things like list comprehensions, but if you are going to be doing matrix computations or machine learning you want to be using Numpy

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that is no actual need. I'm just very curious in general and like to stay informed - at leasst at a general level. Just read a lot about numpy here, so I'll keep that in mind. As I prefer to learn about machines;-), I have enough other stuff currently.

Answer (score 0):

I believed (BUT I WAS *WRONG* - see comments) that the correct way to avoid copying the list is to use slice assignment and a generator expression:

```
a[:] = (i+1 for i in a)
```

The problem with using a list comprehension `[i+1 for i in a]` is that it will first build a new list, and then the slice assignment will iterate over the temporary list to bind each element of `a` to the value.

With the generator expression, one iterates over the existing list lazily as the slice assignment requests additional values, so no temporary list ever needs to be created in principle. However - as I was corrected - the slice assignment causes a list to be created from the generator expression.

Comment: You might think this would avoid a copy, but it doesn't. [`list_ass_slice`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ff95708d4427/Objects/listobject.c#l646) calls `PySequence_Fast` on the generator, undoing your efforts and turning it into a list anyway.

Comment: Could you explain what `a[:] =` does that's different from `a =`?

Comment: @user2357112 - wow - thanks for the correction. I edited the answer accordingly. I guess I should leave this up as (I at least) find it fairly informative.

Comment: @SU3: It's a slice assignment. It's a lot like what you'd expect assigning one `vector` to another `vector` to do in C++; instead of setting the `a` variable to refer to the thing on the right, it mutates the list `a` refers to, making it contain the elements of the thing on the right.

Answer (score -1):

**`Ans to Q#1`** - Once we further manipulate the array (or array elements) then it is like a reference to the original array with persistent new changes to it. It can be called as an `intermediate` copy but apparently not a copy of original array.

**`Ans to Q#2`** - Python internally doesn't optimize `a` as such as mentioned in your question.

Though you can get the desired results with:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
a = [i+1 for i in a]
print a
```

Still using **`slicing`** notation **`:`** will be much appropriate:

```
a[:] = [i+1 for i in a]
print a
```

*** Thanks to @Paul Rooney for sharing the example.

Comment: Nope. The array elements are objects. The list just hold references to them. So changing the values of these objects does not actually change the list. Assigning an element to another list will also just copy the reference, not the element. Note that Python significantly differes from C/C++ in this aspect, as _everything_ is an object: Ints are objects, no scalars. Yo actually create a new list, but not new objects. That does not answer the question.

Comment: So did yo mean it can be called as an intermediate copy of an original array ?

Comment: No, it is an intermediate array containing the incremented values, but apparently no _copy_ for the original.

Answer (score -2):

To increment each element in your list without creating another copy of the list, you should follow @Akavall's answer.

Re your question if list comprehension creates an intermediate copy of the list, following is the explanation.

List comprehension

```
a = [i+1 for i in a]
```

can be expanded as:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(i+1)
a = b
```

As you can see, we are traversing the list and increment each element one by one. These elements are stored in a temp list and that new list is assigned back to `a`.

In this case, `a` is just a label that's referencing the list. `a = b` simply updates the reference to point to new list.

Comment: That does not answer the question. It has even explicitly be excluded. Note that b is a `dict`, not a list.

Comment: I'm answering his question if the list comprehension is creating a new copy of a list or doing it in place.

Comment: "What is the most pythonic way to do it in situ, without copying the list?"